# Lambda + shared_ptr

Tags: c++, lambda

Вот пример:

```
static std::function<MyClass*()> myFunc;

void main() {
   auto sp = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
   myFunc = [&]{ return sp.get() } ;
   ...
}

void f() {
   ...
   auto pMyClass = myFunc ? muFunc() : null_ptr ;
   if ( pMyClass ) {
      pMyClass->metod();
   }
}
```

Как лучше захватывать указатель из sp для лямбды? Правильно ли я делаю захват по ссылке?
Чтобы только вызвать `metod()` верно ли возвращать обычный указатель, а не сам shared_ptr из лямбды? Или лучше вообще сделать `[&]()-> shared_ptr<MyClass>& { return sp }` ? (заранее извиняюсь, если синтаксис неверный)

Comment: Лучше просто использовать умный указаьель (мастерство заключается в умении  делать проще, а не создавать лишные сложности, дабы придать  созданию заумный вид):    auto sp = std::make_shared<MyClass>(); sp->metod().

Comment: Мне интересно именно как лучше захватывать и возвращать умные указатели в лямбде

Comment: Ну, в таком случаи,  захват по ссыльке или захват по значению зависит от задачи..   Так как  std::shared_ptr при копировании просто передает право владения своей копии, то   копировать  вполне нормально и возвращать его копию тоже нормално. Так что ваш вопрос слышком общий , и можно на вопрос ответить  для конкретной задачи.  Я вообше пока не представляю вариант, когда  неудобно прямо в лямбде создать то же   std::shared_ptr и возвращать его, а не создавать в окружении, потом захватывать в лямбде, обработать и возвращать. Вы все  сделали правилоьно

Comment: когда я говорю, что вы все сделали правильно, я имею ввиду, что этот вариант вполне  нормальный с точки зрения языка